# transfer array to array in assembly getting weird output. why?

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, nasm

im trying to understand how to manipulate arrays for a class, but even the code exactely the same as found in the support material i getting this issue

in this site is a code that i get some inspiration to that
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/assembly_programming/assembly_arrays.htm
is quite the same loop im doing in my code also the mov parts.
dont know if is related to the problem, im using a online ide: https://www.jdoodle.com/compile-assembler-nasm-online
to run the code.

```
section .text

global _start

_start:

    mov     eax,5
    mov     ebx,[x]
    mov     ecx,[y]
transfere:
    mov     ecx,ebx
    add     ebx,1
    add     ecx,1
    dec     eax
    jnz     transfere

    mov     [y],ecx


    mov     eax,4
    mov     ebx,1
    mov     ecx,y
    mov     edx,10
    int     0x80

    mov     eax, 1
    int     0x80

section .data

    x times 5 dw '5'
    y times 5 dw 0
```

i expect to get 5.5.5.5.5.  as output but im getting 9.5.......

Comment: Some of your `mov` operations (e.g. `mov     ebx,[x]`) do not match the size of the elements in your arrays; `dw` defines a _word_ (i.e. 16 bits), while the `e_x` registers are doublewords (32 bits).

Comment: Also, the only place you ever write anything to `y` is `mov     [y],ecx`. I don't see how you expected to copy 10 bytes with a single 32-bit `mov`.

Comment: Single-step your code with a debugger like GDB to see memory and registers change.  The online "IDE" appears to be missing a debugger, so it's nearly useless for learning asm.  (And the example it loads up when you go to https://www.jdoodle.com/compile-assembler-nasm-online is bad: it loads 4 bytes from two single-byte `db` locations in the `.data` section, and stores 4 bytes to `sum resb 1` where they only reserved 1 byte.  It doesn't actually cause a problem because it only prints the 1st byte, and it's not linking with anything that would get its variables stepped on, but it's a bad example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem is with the instructions

```
    mov ebx, [x]
    mov ecx, [y]
```

which will simply load the first 32 bits of the arrays `x` and `y` into `ebx` and `ecx` respectively. What I assume you want to do is to load the addresses of thes arrays into these two registers, i.e.

```
    mov ebx, x
    mov ecx, y
```

Now `ebx` and `ecx` contains the address of the first bytes of the arrays. The instruction (after the label)

```
transfere:
    mov ecx, ebx
```

also does not do what you (probably) expect, namely copy data from the first array to the other. All it does is copy the value stored in `ebx` into `ecx`, so this will lose the address of the second array. What you need to do in order to copy **the word located at the address pointed to by `ebx`** to **the word located at the address pointed to by `ecx`** is

```
    mov dx, [ebx]
    mov [ecx], dx
```

(A `mov`-instruction can only have one memory operand, so we first copy the word into a word register, `dx` in this case, and then copy `dx` into the memory pointed to by `ecx`. We need to use a word register (16 bits), rather than a dword register, such as `edx` here). After this is done, we need to make `ecx` and `ebx` point to the next word, which is 2 bytes after the current address. So we do

```
    add ebx, 2
    add ecx, 2
```

The loop is otherwise fine, but the instruction immediately following it needs to be removed:

```
    mov [y], ecx
```

This will copy the value of `ecx` (a memory address) into the array `y`, which will result in garbage being printed (as this address is interpreted as 4 characters).
So the finished program looks like:

```
section .text

global _start

_start:

    mov     eax, 5
    mov     ebx, x
    mov     ecx, y
transfere:
    mov     dx, [ebx]
    mov     [ecx], dx
    add     ebx, 2
    add     ecx, 2
    dec     eax
    jnz     transfere

    mov     eax, 4
    mov     ebx, 1
    mov     ecx, y
    mov     edx, 10
    int     0x80

    mov     eax, 1
    int     0x80

section .data

    x times 5 dw '5'
    y times 5 dw 0
```

Here is a shorter version, which uses fewer registers (the beginning and ending are identical to the above program, and are omitted):

```
_start:

    mov     eax,5
transfere:
    mov     bx, [x + eax*2 - 2]
    mov     [y + eax*2 - 2], bx
    dec     eax
    jnz     transfere

    ...
```

Comment: Nice explanation.  Welcome to Stack Overflow!  I'd suggest `movzx ebx, word [x + eax*2 - 2]` to avoid a false dependency on the old value of `ebx`, but just using a 16-bit `mov` is maybe simpler.  And of course if you care about efficiency, you'd copy in 32-bit chunks, or maybe 8 bytes with SSE2 `movq`.  (glibc memcpy has a pretty nice strategy of 2 possibly-overlapping loads+stores to handle various sizes...)

Comment: thank you very much! i couldn find any material to explain this nuances in my code or in any code. do you know something that will help me?